# How to clear jetpack datastore data on specific condition

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-datastore

i've been using jetpack datastore for a while, but then i got a problem.
I want to clear data in datastore when the app is destroyed.
Im using jetpack datastore to persist data only in form

i've searched that sharedPreferences has a clear() function, is there a similar function for Jetpack Datastore ? and how can i use it ?

i found clear function in
[datastore documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/datastore/preferences/package-summary#clear) but there is no explanation on how to use it

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Use this

```
dataStore.edit { 
        it.clear()
    }
```

Method description states

> Removes all preferences from this MutablePreferences.

For proto datastore (Thanks to Amir Raza for comment)

```
datastore.updateData { 
    it.toBuilder().clear().build()
}
```

Comment: how can i use this on proto datastore ?

Comment: for proto datastore -> `datastore.updateData { it.toBuilder().clear().build() }`

Comment: How to delete for specific preferences key?

Comment: @A.Albrg you can set to null

Comment: @AdeDyas Can u write a sample code, please :)

Comment: @AdeDyas - no you can't. But if you'd like to show us how, that'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @A.Albrg check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66746767/2212770)

Answer (score 48):

In case anyone wants to know how to remove a specific preference

```
context.dataStore.edit {
    it.remove(key)
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this (for Proto DataStore):

```
 dataStore.updateData { obj ->
    obj.toBuilder()
        .clear()
        .build()
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to delete a specific key then try this

```
dataStore.edit {
        if (it.contains(key)) {
            it.remove(key)
        }
    }
```

Comment: But `it` refers to `MutablePreferences`. So `it.clear()` would clear all preferences instead of a specific key.

Comment: It should be `it.remove(key)`, I also posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66746767/2212770). The contains check is also not necessary because no exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

For Proto DataStore you can do:

dataStore.updateData { it.getDefaultInstance() }

It doesn't delete the file, but it's effectively the same.

Comment: so, this method means it will make dataStore to default data ?

Answer (score 0):

#### in RxDataStore

**try this to clear all saved data**

```
    dataStore.updateDataAsync {
            val clear = it.toMutablePreferences().apply {
                this.clear()
            }
            Single.just(clear)
        }
```