# how to set logout in preferences DataStore at Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, logout, preferences, android-jetpack-datastore

We use ".clear" in shared preferences before, to setting the button logout. But now i tried to use preferences datastore, but can't use the same code. So how? Thank you so much for answering..

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64851765/how-to-clear-jetpack-datastore-data-on-specific-condition) answer

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
dataStore.edit { 
        it.clear()
    }
```

In case anyone wants to know how to remove a specific preference

```
context.dataStore.edit {
    it.remove(key)
}
```

Try this (for Proto DataStore):

```
dataStore.updateData { obj ->
    obj.toBuilder()
        .clear()
        .build()
 }
```